# Store maximum frequency

Tags: matlab, fft

I am working on a script which performs a FFT of given short audio file in a loop. I also want to store the peak frequency but I do not know how to do that.

The code looks similar to this:

```
n = ...
Frequencies = zeros(1,n); % Allocating memory for the peak frequencies

for k = 1:n
    str(k)
    textFileName = [num2str(k) '.m4a'];
    [data,fs] = audioread(textFileName);

    %...
    % Fast Fourier transform and plotting part works ok
    %...

    [peaks,frequencies] = findpeaks(abs(cutP2),cutf,'MinPeakHeight',10e-3);

    % Here starts the problem
    maximum_Peak = max(peaks);
    Frequencies(k) = ... % I need to store the frequency which is coupled 
                         % with the maximum amplitude but I do not know how
end

close(figure(n)) %The loop opens one redundant blank plot, I could not 
                 %find out any other way to close it
```

I do not want to store the amplitudes of peak frequencies, but frequencies of peak amplitudes. If you could help me with the redundant figure, I would be happy. I tried to implement an `if` statement but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` contains a second output which returns the index of the maximum value. Use this second value to stores the value of interest.

```
[maximum_Peak,I] = max(peaks); %Note I Use 'I' for index - personal habit
Frequencies(k) = frequencies(I);
```

Also, if your goal is only to find the max point findpeaks may be overkill and you could potentially use:

```
[maximum_Peak,I] = max(abs(cutP2));
%Might want to check that max is high enough
Frequencies(k) = cutf(I);
```

Note although the code is similar it is not the same and depends on what you want to do.

Finally, some unsolicited advice, your use of `frequencies` and `Frequencies` is a bit of a red flag. Generally differences based on capitalization are not a good idea. Consider renaming the latter to `freq_of_max_amp`